# Why does assigning my input to enum cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I have the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dbg.h"

#define MAX_DATA 100

typedef enum EyeColor{
    BLUE_EYES, GREEN_EYES, BROWN_EYES, BLACK_EYES, OTHER_EYES
} EyeColor;

const char *EYE_COLOR_NAMES[] = {
    "Blue", "Green", "Brown", "Black", "Other"
};

typedef struct Person {
    int age;
    char first_name[MAX_DATA];
    char last_name[MAX_DATA];
    EyeColor eyes;
    float income;
} Person;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Person you = {.age = 0};
    int i = 0;
    char *in = NULL;

    printf("What's your First Name? ");
    in = fgets(you.first_name, MAX_DATA-1, stdin);  //fgets is much better
    check(in != NULL, "Failed to read first name.");

    printf("What's your Last Name? ");
    in = fgets(you.last_name, MAX_DATA-1, stdin);
    check(in != NULL, "Failed to read last name.");

    printf("How old are you? ");
    int rc = fscanf(stdin, "%d", &you.age);
    check(rc > 0, "You have to enter a number.");

    printf("What color are your eyes:\n");
    for(i = 0; i <= OTHER_EYES; i++) {
        printf("%d) %s\n", i+1, EYE_COLOR_NAMES[i]);
    }
    printf("> ");

    int eyes = -1;
    rc = fscanf(stdin, "%d", &eyes);
    check(rc > 0, "You have to enter a number.");

    you.eyes = eyes - 1;
    //check(you.eyes <= OTHER_EYES && you.eyes >= 0, "Do it right, that's not an option.");     // if you dont check this, seg fault can happen because of ...

    printf("How much do you make an hour? ");
    rc = fscanf(stdin, "%f", &you.income);
    check(rc > 0, "Enter a floating point number.");

    printf("------ RESULTS ------\n ");

    printf("First Name: %s", you.first_name);
    printf("Last Name: %s", you.last_name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", you.age);
    printf("Eyes: %s\n", EYE_COLOR_NAMES[you.eyes]);
    printf("Income: %f\n", you.income);

    return 0;
error:
    return 1;
}
```

If I ran:
$./ex24

and I give the following input:

```
What's your First Name? a
What's your Last Name? b
How old are you? 1
What color are your eyes:
1) Blue
2) Green
3) Brown
4) Black
5) Other
> 1000
How much do you make an hour? 1
------ RESULTS ------
 First Name: a
Last Name: b
Age: 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How does this seg fault happen? Isn't that enum is allocating int type in my memory that should be able to hold 1000?

EDIT 1: format some text into code.
EDIT 2: comment out the check.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: "is allocating int type in my memory that should be able to hold 1000?" – aww, you're *extremely* confused about how memory works. (In particular, if an integer value doesn't fit into a variable, then the high bits just get truncated.) But I'd bet the segfault is not arising out of a mere assignment to a variable of type `enum`. Use a debugger!

Comment: please post the `check` functioin.

Comment: @iharob: We do not need to see the `check` function. He has entered `1000` as input. He is asking why the code segfaults when the call to `check` is removed. The reason is plainly clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the enum can go up to 1000; your array does not have 1000 elements.
There is no 1000<sup>th</sup> eye colour to print out.

Here's the testcase you should have constructed:

```
#include <iostream>

const char* EYE_COLOR_NAMES[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
const int eyes = 1000;

int main()
{
    std::cout << EYE_COLOR_NAMES[eyes] << '\n';
}
```

I'd say it's obvious that this can't work.

You already have the range check for `you.eyes` in your code, and you have found out yourself that the segmentation fault can only occur if you take the range check out. So, simply leave the range check in.

Comment: I didn't see that, it's not visible. Sorry.

Comment: I was going to answer the same, but suddenly I saw the chek, just didn't see the comment.

Comment: @iharob: It's disguised quite well in the question. The OP wasn't very clear and should have posted a testcase.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes, you are right about the comment. I have commented out the line with the check. I will check your test case.

Comment: @dennycrane valid indices for this array are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. What did you expect `EYE_COLOR_NAMES[1000]` to do exactly?

Comment: (A very minor point: *the testcase you should have constructed* should be in C, not C++.)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, you mean enum is an array in C? What is the data type of the array entry?

Comment: @dannycrane: No, enums are not arrays. You can entirely forget the enum as it is not relevant to your problem. _Whatever_ the array element type is, you're trying to access elements that don't exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, could you explain a bit about how enum is organized in memory? that is actually what I am interested in (the reason I put 1000 there).

Comment: @dannycrane: You're not listening to me. The enum is _irrelevant_. It doesn't matter. You can make your array an array of elephants and have the same issue. As for "how it's organised in memory", well, it's _not_: it's just an integer type. The enum names only exist at compile-time. You're not even _using_ the enum so I don't see why you're going on about it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes. I realize the basic problem now...Thank you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, but I still wonder what enum looks like in memory.

Comment: @dannycrane: That's a different question and could be posted as such. But an enum doesn't "look like" anything in memory. Enum names are just integer constants.